# What kind of object is this in from mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried to query some data from our remote company db it returns something like this. It is a very weird data. As you can see it has a key "1"

```
{
            "services" : {
                "1" : {
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-10-19T06:40:33.583Z"),
                    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-10-19T06:40:33.583Z")
                }
            },
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-10-19T06:40:33.583Z")
        },
```

I tried logging like this `console.log(subscription.services[0])` it outputs `undefined`
I tried logging it using `console.log(Object.keys(subscription.services[0]))`
It output like this

```
[ '__parentArray',
  '__index',
  '$isDocumentArrayElement',
  '$__',
  'isNew',
  'errors',
  '$locals',
  '$op',
  '_doc',
  '$init' ]
```

basically I cant access the dates inside the object

here is the full code

UPDATE: I included my query code and logging

```
 const cursor = await Company.find({$and: [
      { "subscriptions":{ $exists: true, $ne: [] }
      }
    ]}).cursor();

await cursor.eachAsync(async company => {
company.subscriptions.find(subscription =>{
        if(subscription.services.length === 1)
        console.log('=========',Object.keys(subscription.services[0]),subscription.services[0]);
      })
})
```

Comment: What do you mean, "what kind of object is this"? It's an object you have stored in your database.

Comment: When you query the database, you get documents; these can be zero, one or more in number. MongoDB stores data as documents. See [Databases and Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/databases-and-collections/)

Comment: @prasad I can't access the dates inside the object. As you can see the key is "1"

Comment: Looks like revisions data.  Show how you are accessing, querying, updating, and adding data.

Comment: " As you can see the key is '1' " - yes, why are you not using this key (`subscription.services["1"]`, for example)?

Comment: It is undefined

Comment: @zero298 I think you are right.. I updated the data then query from it then it add a new data on my collection something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
 const companies = await Company.find({ "subscriptions":{ "$nin": [ null, "" ] }).lean()

 companies.map((company) => {
   company.subscriptions.find(subscription => {
        if(subscription.services.length === 1) {
    console.log('=========',Object.keys(subscription.services[0]),subscription.services[0]);
    })
})
```

Comment: But I already get the data?

Comment: Can you copy your code request here please ? :)

Comment: consider editing or removing this answer now that OP has updated their question! :)